# Which c++ R-tree library can deal with the arbitrarily high-dimensional points easily?

Tags: dimension, tree-traversal, r-tree

I am doing the research on R-tree, recently I use the R-tree of boost, but I found it is hard to fill a high dimension points ( dimension > 3).

Is there any other c++ R-tree library can create the points easily at will?

I found the same problem in the past
[Defining a dimensional point in Boost.Geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118764/defining-a-dimensional-point-in-boost-geometry)

I want a r-tree library which initialises high-dimension points in r-tree easily, because I am doing the research on R-tree and I want to do the traversal for R-tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest Boost for high dimensions and I explain in my pseudo-site [why](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/approximate-nearest-neighbors-nn-libraries-in-high-dimensions-flann-vs-cgal-vs-boost/).

I would suggest you to use [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/), which may use RKD-trees or k-means and can perform Approximate Nearest Neihgbour Search.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237575/comparison-of-the-runtime-of-nearest-neighbor-queries-on-different-data-structur/26266337#26266337) answer for more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  I am sorry I forgot to say that I am not do the NN search, I want to traversal the R-tree. But thank you very much that you let me know an efficient NN search library.