# Construct n-dimensional boost point

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, point, n-dimensional

**Problem:**
boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp point template does not provide a way to construct an n-dimensional point type *with* non-zero values.

For example:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

...
typedef bg::model::point<double,4,bg::cs::cartesian> point;

auto nDimPoint1 = point(); // creates a point with 4 values each 0
auto nDimPoint2 = point(1,2,3,4); // !!!compiler error!!! since point's template does not provide a strategy past 3 dimensions.

// workaround, but must be hard-coded
nDimPoint1.set<0>(1);
nDimPoint1.set<1>(2);
nDimPoint1.set<2>(3);
nDimPoint1.set<3>(4);
```

**What I've tried:**
After reading through boost's documentation I was not able to find any examples with n-dimensional points, though it is possible I missed them.

I did encounter creating custom point classes and registering them, but the built in point class accomplishes exactly what I want. Unfortunately I can't solve this by inheriting from the base point since the point representation is a private variable.

Point's template contains a private array variable, `m_values`, by creating a new constructor which takes a vector and copying the vector into `m_values` I was able to fix the issue.

I'm also pretty new to C++'s templates, since I usually use C and python. Is it possible to extend the Point template outside the Point.hpp file to include the n-dimensional constructor I want? Or is there a better way of building n-dimensional points in boost such as cast from vector?

Ideally (imho) boost would provide a generic copy constructor which accepts std::vector and copies each value into its internal array.

Related questions:
In this question [Defining a dimensional point in Boost.Geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23118764/10448495), the author is attempting to utilize point for rtree (I am also attempting to do this), however the accepted answer claims this is not possible and a second solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777496/10448495, claims to solve the issue, but I don't see how it can work.

Comment: Boost is open source, so you can take and extend it to fulfill your desires. I'm sure they'd also happily accept feature requests with a patch. One note though, supplying a `std::vector` probably won't find much favor. Instead, provide a constructor that takes an initializer list (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: Yeah, although the accepted answer works, I completely missed the STD_ARRAY in the documentation. Would still be nice (and intuitive) if the default point class accepted an array as input, so I will probably join their dev-mailing list and see if I can introduce this new constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The model::point class template doesn't afford direct/aggregate initialization and it's not possible to add that (`m_values` is private e.g., but also there is optional access-tracking debug metadata that would get out of sync).

Note the class is documented

> ```
> \details Defines a neutral point class, fulfilling the Point Concept.
>     Library users can use this point class, or use their own point classes.
>     This point class is used in most of the samples and tests of Boost.Geometry
>     This point class is used occasionally within the library, where a temporary
>     point class is necessary.
> ```

And:

> ```
> \tparam DimensionCount number of coordinates, usually 2 or 3
> ```

So, you can - and probably should - use your own type. The simplest thing would be to use an array directly (so, just the `m_values` member data really). There's very little magic about that:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9EPh46nn7)**

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/std_array.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_STD_ARRAY_CS(bg::cs::cartesian)

using point = std::array<double, 4>;

int main() {
    auto a = point(); // creates a point with 4 values each 0
    auto b = point{1, 2, 3, 4}; 

    // generic Boost code will still work:
    bg::set<0>(a, 10);
    bg::set<1>(a, 20);
    bg::set<2>(a, 30);
    bg::set<3>(a, 40);

    fmt::print("default:{}, a:{}, b:{}\n", point{}, a, b);
}
```

Prints

```
default:[0, 0, 0, 0], a:[10, 20, 30, 40], b:[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't run across this functionality in the boost documentation on points, but now that I look I see that point concept documentation references STD_ARRAY_CS here, for anyone looking for the documentation. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_point.html.

Comment: +100 The newest version has a more comprehensive documentation there https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_point.html